# show "select option" as default value in JQuery UI select

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using the JQuery UI to be able to show images within a select box:

see
http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render

But how using this can I make "Select an option" the default value that appears within the selectbox but also does not show when the select drops down?

Thanks!

HTML code is as follows

```
 <fieldset>
    <select name="filesA" id="country">
                            <option data-class="austria" /> Austria</option>
                            <option data-class="belgium"/> Belgium</option>
                            <option data-class="bulgaria" />Bulgaria</option>          
... 


    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

include "Select an option" as one of the option and disable the option, So the user can't select it. Here is the code

```
<fieldset>
    <select name="filesA" id="country">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="true" /> Select an Option</option>
        <option data-class="austria" /> Austria</option>
        <option data-class="belgium"/> Belgium</option>
        <option data-class="bulgaria" />Bulgaria</option>                 
    </select>
  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks that works but select an option still appears when you drop down? Is there a way of hiding it from the dropped down list¿